# Best method for mango pulp-juice separation?

Tags: equipment

I am not sure whether this would be the best place to ask or some other group, but let’s try:

Making mango wine I am currently blending fresh fruit and sieving the pulp with a thin filter (kitchen equipment, not sure of the exact size of the filter).

I used to add water to the pulp to manage it better but that led to loss of sugar, flavor and  acidity. After primary, sediment would be 1/3 of the initial volume.

I then tried using pure pulp and the sediment after primary would be about 1/2.

I’ve tried to get thinner juice by removing solids. I acquired a press with filter bags and pressed the fruit but the consistency of the pulp prevents juice flow before enzyme and fermentation. And when I tried the same method after enzyme and / or fermentation, the particles are so thin that they squeeze out under pressure of the press.

A method that has some degree of success was pouring some amount of pulp in a filter bag, and manually centrifuging the bag inside a bucket. Somehow the movement and pressures combined seem to work better than using the press alone. However this method isn’t sanitary and not scalable.

I’m trying to find out what equipment and method I could be using to extract the juice from the pulp of mango, and get a really thin juice.

I’m not sure if this problem is unique to mango, because with other fruits I use, the juice is either thin or the pulp can easily be separated from the juice.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Considering all the methods you have already tried I'd consider using pectinase to break down the fruit before you press or spin the juice out, that should give you at least a bit more juice.

Boiling the fruit before trying to get the juice should also help break down the fruit a bit more and allow more juice to be collected.

Have you tried a tiered approach? Like a sieve first, then spinning, and finally using your press?
I'd try something like that to get as much of the liquid out first, then let the solids settle out and racking off the pure juice.